# How do you translate "to realize" in "We realized that we are not alone"?

Tags: single-word-requests

How do you translate "to realize" in `We realized that we are not alone`?

I found the word *realigi*, but it means to make something real/true. It does not mean that we became aware of something.

Answer (score 5):

"Ni ekkonsciis, ke ni ne estas solaj" aŭ "Ni konsciiĝis, ke ni ne estas solaj"

Answer (score 5):

The words you need are *ekscii, ekkonscii, ekkompreni* for fairly rapid realizations, and *sciiĝi, konsciiĝi, komprenantiĝi* for slower ones. *Konstati* can be used for *realize* but it is more along the lines of *confirm, determine*; i.e. it refers to a confirmation of a suspicion, an increase in certainty.

- *Ŝi eksciis, ke la afero estis jam finita.* She knew straight away that the business was already over.
- *Li ekkonsciis, ke li ne estis sola.* He became aware that he was not alone.
- *Li ekkomprenis, ke ŝi ne volis resti en la restoracio.* He realized that she didn't want to stay in the restaurant.
- *Ŝi sciiĝis, ke jam la aliaj apenaŭ povis regi la maŝinojn.* She gradually realized that the others could already barely control the machines.
- *Li konsciiĝis, ke aliaj homoj nun staris en la ĉambro.* He became conscious of the fact that other people were now standing in the room.
- *Ŝi komprenantiĝis, ke li neniam venos al la kuracisto sen devigo.* She came to understand that he would never go to the doctor without being compelled.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure there are many alternatives, but the first one to spring to mind is *konstati*.

From vortaro.net (PIV):

- Rimarki, rigardi ion, kies faktecon, realecon oni post esplorado asertas: la kuracisto povis nur konstati la mortonB; konstati ies foreston; konstati la identecon de la kriminto; ni konstatas, ke vi rifuzas respondi; la protokolo konstatis, ke […]; estas konstatite, ke […]; facile konstatebla fakto.

Benson (CEED) suggests *konstati* and *konscii*.

Wells suggests *kompreni* and *konstati.*

If you're at the point where you're asking questions like this, it would be a good idea to invest in a good bilingual dictionary - especially if this answer is not well-addressed in the on-line dictionaries.